# Adding charset to the response header

Tags: java, http, tomcat, servlets

I am using following to run my web application -

1. Eclipse
2. Java 1.6_21
3. Tomcat

When i run my application on my local machine using eclipse, in the response header i can see that Content-Type is set to following -

**Content-Type:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1**

But when i run my application on the production servers by deploying war file in the tomcat then the Content-Type in the response header is set to following -

**Content-Type:text/html**

I want to know how charset=ISO-8859-1 is set when i run application on my local machine and why it is not getting set on the production environment.

Do I need to do something in the tomcat configuration on the production environment to ensure that chartset is set into the Content-Type or the problem lies somewhere else?

Comment: What version of tomcat? Is it the same on your machine and in production? Isn't there a frontend server like Apache in production? Also, why use ISO and not UTF-8?

Comment: @fge ISO-8859-1 is sort of the unofficial default for web pages when none is specified (although there's zillions of exceptions); it's fairly reasonable although I agree UTF-8 is a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For servlets, you can just set it in the response, e.g.:

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1");
response.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
```

For JSP, you set it in a page directive:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" %>
```

For Tomcat global, the answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/236391/how-can-i-change-the-default-encoding-of-a-tomcat-server-container) may help.